# Combobox enabled state reset after partial postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, callback, updatepanel, viewstate

### Background

I have a search feature that allows the end user to search for items in a database. This search feature has a textbox, two comboboxes and a button.

When one of the combobox items is selected the other's value changes and it's set to be disabled. This is done by Javascript and works.

All of the controls are within an updatepanel.

### Problem

After the callback made by the updatepanel is completed the combobox that was disabled is being reset, rendering it as enabled.

### My Guess

The changes made by the Javascript aren't being saved to the viewstate and sent back in the initial request.

**Can anyone shine some light on this problem?**

### Code

ASP

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UPJobDetailSearch" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
            <ContentTemplate>
              <div id="searchbox" class="searchbox">
                    <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="TxtSearchTerm" runat="server" CssClass="searchbox" name="searchbox" NullText="Search for.." SkinID="None" />
                </div>
                <div id="searchcombo">
                     <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="CbSearchCriteria" ClientInstanceName="CbSearchCriteria" Width="150" CssClass="combobox" AutoPostBack="false" NullText="Choose Criteria" runat="server" SelectedIndex="-1" SkinID="None">
                    <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="CbSearchCriteria" ClientInstanceName="CbSearchCriteria" Width="150" CssClass="combobox" AutoPostBack="false" NullText="Choose Criteria" runat="server" SelectedIndex="-1" SkinID="None">
                        <Items>
                            <dx:ListEditItem Text="Id" Value="ID" />
                            <dx:ListEditItem Text="Num" Value="NUM" />
                        </Items>
                    </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                </div>
                <div id="searchLocationcombo">
                    <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="CbSearchLocationCriteria" ClientInstanceName="CbSearchLocationCriteria" CssClass="combobox" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" NullText="Location" SelectedIndex="-1" SkinID="None"
                        ClientSideEvents-SelectedIndexChanged="function(s,e){ ChangeSearchCriteriaItem(s,e); }">
                        <Items>
                            <dx:ListEditItem Text="Jobs" Value="Jobs" />
                            <dx:ListEditItem Text="Comms" Value="Comms" />
                        </Items>
                    </dx:ASPxComboBox>
                </div>
                <div id="SearchBtn" class="searchbtn">
                    <dx:ASPxButton ID="BtnSearch" CssClass="BtnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="BtnSearch_Click" ClientSideEvents-Click="function(){ ShowSearching(); }" />
                </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

NB. My controls are DevExpress aspx controls. (I wouldn't imagine this would matter though)

Javascript

```
 function ChangeSearchCriteriaItem(s, e) {
            debugger;

            var cmbLocationCriteria = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName("CbSearchLocationCriteria")
            var selecteditem = cmbLocationCriteria.GetSelectedItem();
            var cmbSearchCriteria = ASPxClientControl.GetControlCollection().GetByName("CbSearchCriteria");

            if (selecteditem.text == "Comms Log") {

                cmbSearchCriteria.SetValue("JobId");
                cmbSearchCriteria.SetEnabled(false);
            }
            else {
                cmbSearchCriteria.SetEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem in WebForms. And yes, your guess is right. The enabled state isn't saved in the ViewState.

The best way would be to use the pageLoad function:

```
<script> 
   ///<summary>
   ///  This will fire on initial page load, 
   ///  and all subsequent partial page updates made 
   ///  by any update panel on the page
   ///</summary>
   function pageLoad(){ alert('page loaded!') }  
</script>
```

In the pageLoad function you can reset the enabled state if necessary.

**Second option**

You could also try to register a ClientScript in your CodeBehind on the postback event, the third argument would be your JavaScript function and would be called after the postback has finished. In this example you would set the enabled state in the function 'javascriptFunctionName':

```
ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
       typeof(page1), 
       "CssFix", 
       "javascriptFunctionName()", 
        true);
```

Comment: Yes i also have this idea, by disabling it again in the JS  `window.onload` event. However it didn't seem to fire on a callback due it the update panel. Is this what you mean?.

Comment: The window.onload function is not the same as the pageLoad function. If you define a pageLoad function in your JavaScript it will fire also on every partial postBack event.

Comment: Okay, I'm looking into this now. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the function has to be named 'pageLoad' and only one pageLoad function is allowed per page.

Comment: Yep that worked. Didn't know about pageLoad(). So thank you for pointing that one out. Do you know why Asp acts in this way, ignoring the state of the combobox? Is it due to the use of Javascript?

Comment: The ViewState per default only saves .text and .value fields of a control, attributes (like 'enabled') are not saved.
Furthermore, setting a style value on client-side does not update the ViewState. You have to set the style on server-side if you want to store it in ViewState.

Comment: Thank you @tipura.